ROS and LXC and X11 server problem
I am currently running into a series of problems and about to lose my mind.
I am new to ros 1 and Ubuntu systems, I am running a dual boot of Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Inside Ubuntu 22.04 I have installed the lxc container service, and setup a new container for Ubuntu 20.04.
(If someone asked why do not you install 20.04 directly dual boot I would say I wish I could! there were infinite problems with dual booting 20.04 on my Asus laptop, the last problem was that the keyboard not working so I downloaded 22.04 to be compatible with my laptop, as I have searched and found that new laptops are not quite compatible with old Ubuntu versions).
Anyway, now I have installed the lxc ubuntu 20.04 container and named it "ros1", to install ros 1 on my container I followed the exact instructions from ros neotic installation, using this link. The ros 1 was successfully installed, and roscore is running ok, but the tutlesim is not working!!
When I try the command rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node, it gives me the following error:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
Aborted (core dumped) 

After a lot and a lot of searching, I figured out that the problem was in the X11 server regarding the GPU set.
I tried to set it and allow the permissions but I could not, every command I ran about X11 said permission denied, for example, lxc exec ros1 -- bash -c 'export DISPLAY=:1'
gives me the error:
Error: Get "http://unix.socket/1.0": dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied"

and yes my export DISPLAY  command is set to port :1 not :0, I am sure that I am :1 and tested it by running the command xeyes on my host, it works well!
But inside the ros1 container of ubuntu 20.04 if I tried to run xeyes it says can not open
Error: Can't open display: :1

So, I need to enable the X11 server on my lxc container I think or things like that, I am not sure what to do I just want to run the rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node command and open the turtle window.
Please anyone could help because I have been in this problem for four complete days and do not know what to do.
